# tone analyzer tutorial getting "code":400,"sub_code":"C00012","error":"Invalid JSON input at line 1, column 2"

Tags: cloud

I'm trying the suggested json data comprising `{"text": "Team, I know that times are tough! Product sales have been disappointing for the past three quarters. We have a competitive product, but we need to do a better job of selling it!"}` without success.  Please advise.

Comment: See tutorial here https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/tone-analyzer?topic=tone-analyzer-gettingStarted

Answer (score 0):

There's an error in the API documentation. The service requires a different json format, like so:

```
{
  "utterances": [
    {
      "text": "Hello, I'm having a problem with your product.",
      "user": "customer"
    },
    {
      "text": "OK, let me know what's going on, please.",
      "user": "agent"
    },
    {
      "text": "Well, nothing is working :(",
      "user": "customer"
    },
    {
      "text": "Sorry to hear that.",
      "user": "agent"
    }
  ]
}
```

See [Specifying JSON input](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/tone-analyzer?topic=tone-analyzer-utco#exampleRequest)